# How to use socket.io and Express.js with IISNode

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io, iis-8

I have setup a windows 2012 r2 server with IIS, IISNode and Rewrite module.
This all seems the work just fine, simple applications with Express also seem to work well.
But when I add socket.io to the application, I get stuck. I get following Error:

*

> GET http://mywebsiteadress/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_ABORTED

*

I use IIS version 8.5.96, express version 4.16.2 and socket.io version 2.0.4.

**Server:**

```
let app = require('express')(),
    server = require('http').Server(app),
    io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(process.env.PORT);

app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

io.on('connection',socket=>{
    socket.emit('test','working');
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

I changed

```
io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

to:

```
io = require('socket.io')(server,{
        path: '/SocketIO/socket.io'
    });
```

And now i'm getting this error:

```
polling-xhr.js:264 GET http://mywebsiteadress/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M6RHmTd 404 (Not Found) 
i.create @ polling-xhr.js:264 
i @ polling-xhr.js:165
o.request @ polling-xhr.js:92 
o.doPoll @ polling-xhr.js:122
r.poll @ polling.js:118 
r.doOpen @ polling.js:63
r.open @ transport.js:80 
r.open @ socket.js:245 
r @ socket.js:119
r @ socket.js:28 
r.open.r.connect @ manager.js:226 
r @ manager.js:69
r @ manager.js:37 
r @ index.js:60 
(anonymous) @ (index):12
```

---

**Client:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Socket IO Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script>
        let socket = io.connect()

        socket.on('test',data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web.config:**

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>

        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="index.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                    <match url="socket.io"/>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.js"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

    <webSocket enabled="false"/>

    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What am I doing wrong? I have searched the internet and this forum, and tried a lot of things, but none seem to solve it for me.
I can't seem to find documentation on setting up Socket.io with IISNode?

I hope someone can help me.

Kind regards

Comment: https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I have already read this and don't seem to find something that is relevant to my problem. Please be more specific.

Comment: can you verify path of the file I think this is the main issue of path

Comment: the path of my socket.io in web.config?

Comment: Yes you are getting me right

Comment: I think the path is fine, because the socket.io folder is in the rigth place.

Comment: Is there really nobody who recognizes this issue or able to explain how to configure socket.io with IIS?

Comment: I may help you probably but you at dig out with your self.

Comment: If I would be able to dig it out myself, I wouldn't be writing this post. So please help and guide me in the right direction.

Comment: @user3156776 did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I haven't, it seems nobody is able to help me out. I did find some solutions but those where 5 years old and didn't work on current versions. I have the feeling nobody has ever wanted this to work again in newer versions. So perhaps they have found another way of doing this, but do not care to share.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your rewrite rule is wrong. Did you forget to add ".+" after your url attribute?

```
 <rule name="SocketIO" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
     <match url="socket.io.+"/>
     <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
 </rule>
```